# Asp.net Core SQLite Database Location

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

In ASP.NET Core when using SQLite database the file `blogger.db` is stored at the root of my project.

I was wondering where the file should go in production? I know it's a bad idea to put it the `wwwroot` folder.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know it's a bad idea to put it the wwwroot folder.

Indeed, because otherwise, it would be potentially accessible as a static file since only those files in `wwwroot` may be served by Static Files Middleware.

> I was wondering where the file should go in production?

The simplest way is to put it in `App_Data` folder.

However, there is no single recommendation on where to store it. Basically, you may put it wherever you want, once you had some restrictions on the `.db` file access.

For instance, you may store it at `C:\data` and have the access to that folder to be restricted only to the account which the application is running under.

Comment: The creators of LiteDb (another embedded database) have a demo in which they place the .db within `wwwroot`
See https://github.com/fabian-blum/AspNetCore.Identity.LiteDB/blob/master/AspNetCore.Identity.LiteDB/AspNetCore.Identity.LiteDB.Demo/appsettings.json